# Horizontally center absolute element inside of relative

Tags: html, css

I'm not able to center an inner, `position: absolute` element inside of an `position: relative` element ( https://jsfiddle.net/qL0c8cau/ ):

```css
html,body,div {margin:0;padding:0;}
.one {
  position: relative;
  margin: 50px auto;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #900;
}
.two {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  background: #0f0;
  opacity: 0.3;
  height: 160px;
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">
  
  <div class="two"></div>
  
</div>
```

I can't see what is wrong with it. I set everything correct, but it's not aligned horizontally for some reason.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: the `margin:auto;` on the `.two` seems suspect. Why are you setting its margins if its absolutely positioned?

Comment: @zgood because this is the way to align it. Take a look how it's aligned from top and bottom. Anyway, I think I got this one.

Comment: I should point it here: it's not about negative values and transform properties. Don't suggest it please, I'm aware of them too

Answer (score 4):

Add this to your css

```css
.two {
  position: absolute;
  top:50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
  margin: auto;
  background: #0f0;
  opacity: 0.3;
  height: 160px;
  width: 400px;
}
```

This code will ensure that, no matter how big your containers are, the inner one will always remain in the centre of the outer one.

```css
html,body,div {margin:0;padding:0;}
.one {
  position: relative;
  margin: 50px auto;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #900;
}
.two {
  position: absolute;
  top:50%;  /* this to center the box w.r.t to parent */
  left: 50%;/* this to center the box w.r.t to parent */
  /* Above 2 lines wont fully center it, the next line internally centers it, buy moving itself 50% left and top */
  transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
  margin: auto;
  background: #0f0;
  opacity: 0.3;
  height: 160px;
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">
  <div class="two"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In div `.two`, instead of using left: 0; and right: 0; to place the div in the center, use `transform: translateX(-25%);` as an alternative. I think the reason the left and right properties don't work is because `.two` is inside `.one`, and it counters the positioning, even though `.two` has a position of absolute.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qL0c8cau/1/)

```
.two {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  transform: translateX(-25%);
  margin: auto;
  background: #0f0;
  opacity: 0.3;
  height: 160px;
  width: 400px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is the inner element's (.two) width is greater than it's parent (.one). I cleaned up (change color and opacity for no confusion) and check it out:

*If you want the inner element width to be greater than it's parent on purpose, check out Guatam's answer

```css
html,
body,
div {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.one {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  position: relative;
  background: red;
}

.two {
  height: 160px;
  width: 160px;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">

  <div class="two"></div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You using a smaller `px` width in the insider `div`

You use `400px` width inside `200px` width

That's why you get it like that

> > If you want to `center` a div, it should be in the size of the relative parent

```css
    html,body,div {margin:0;padding:0;}
    .one {
      position: relative;
      margin: 50px auto;
      width: 400px;
      height: 100px;
      background: #900;
    }
    .two {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      right: 0;
      left: 0;
      margin: auto;
      background: #0f0;
      opacity: 0.3;
      height: 160px;
      width: 200px;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="one">
      
      <div class="two"></div>
      
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use flex for your above problem! More convenient and modern solution for your problem.

[Check browser support for flex](https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox)

```css
.wrap {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.one {
  display: flex;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #fa0;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.two {
  background: #627;
  height: 160px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="one">
    <div class="two"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```